# how to compute homology group Hn(T#T)?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Denote 2-dimensional torus by $T^2=S^1 \times S^1$ ,and unit disc by $ D^2$.Define $$ 
T^2\# T^2=T^2-D^2\cup_{S^1}T^2-D^2 $$
how to compute $H_n(T^2 \# T^2)$

Comment: Did you try Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: could you help me show more details?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187413/computing-the-homology-and-cohomology-of-connected-sum).